# How to stop custom options price to apply on each qty of configurable product? Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, price, custom-options

I have a custom option price which gets applied to each quantity. But I only want to apply that custom option price once instead of applying to each quantity. Below I am adding image of custom option

[image]

No matter how much is the quantity I only want to apply custom option price once to total price for example if I am adding product item with below properties to cart

```
->Price per piece/item = 20.25
->qty = 2
->cusom_option_price = 4
->subtotal = 40.50(20.25 * 2) + 4
->subtotal = 44.50 expected in checkout cart product item subtotal
```

but what I get now is 48.50(actual) in /checkout/cart/ as custom option price is getting applied based on each quantity. I am trying to manipulate \vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php it has functions getFinalPrice and _applyOptionsPrice lets see if that works. Can anyone please guide me through this? it would be really helpful in continuing my learning about magento 2 concepts